# Electric charge operator in the $SU(3)_{C} \times SU(3)_{L} \times U(1)_{X}$ model

Tags: charge, gauge-theory, group-theory, lie-algebra, beyond-the-standard-model

The 3-3-1 extension of the Standard Model of the strong and electroweak interactions, with gauge group $SU(3)_{C} \times SU(3)_{L} \times U(1)_{X}$, provides an attempt to answer the question on family replication. There are several versions of the 3-3-1 models.  In one of them, three $SU(3)_L$ lepton triplets are of the form ($\nu_l, l, \nu_l^c)_L$, where $\nu_l^c$ is related to the right-handed component of the neutrino field $\nu_l$. The particle content of this model is given as follows:
\begin{equation}
\psi_{iL} = \left( \begin{array}{c} \nu_i \\ e_i \\ \nu_i^c \end{array} \right)_L \sim \left( 3, -\frac{1}{3} \right), e_{iR} \sim \left( 1, -1 \right) , i = 1, 2, 3      \tag{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Q_{1L} = \left( \begin{array}{c} u_1 \\ d_1 \\ U \end{array} \right)_L \sim \left( 3, \frac{1}{3} \right), Q_{\alpha L} = \left( \begin{array}{c} d_\alpha \\ -u_\alpha \\ D_\alpha \end{array} \right)_L \sim \left( 3^*, 0 \right), \alpha = 2, 3                   \tag{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_{iR} \sim \left( 1, \frac{2}{3} \right), d_{iR} \sim \left( 1, -\frac{1}{3} \right), U_{R} \sim \left( 1, \frac{2}{3} \right), D_{\alpha R} \sim \left( 1, -\frac{1}{3} \right).         \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Here, the values in the parentheses denote quantum numbers based on the $\left( SU(3)_L, U(1)_X \right)$ symmetry. $U$ and $D_\alpha$ are exotic quarks whose electric charges are the same as of the usual quarks, i.e. $q_U = \frac{2}{3}$ and $q_{D_\alpha} = -\frac{1}{3}$. In this case, the electric charge operator takes the form
\begin{equation}
Q = T_{3} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}T_8 + X             \tag{4}
\end{equation}
where $T_a (a = 1, 2, ..., 8)$ and $X$ stand for $SU(3)_L$ and $U(1)_X$ charges respectively. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0601046) just lists eq. (4) but does not derive it. I wonder how eq. (4) comes about? Why does the electric charge operator take this form? Besides, I am not very familiar with the $SU(3)_L$ charges. What are the values of $T_a$ especially those of $T_3$ and $T_8$ for the particles involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eq. (4) comes about by construction of the model, and should be trivial to check by inspection: it is the *reason* behind constituting the multiplets this way. The generators of *su(3)*, normalized like all generators, *must*, therefore, be the
[Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices) halved,
$$
T_3=\operatorname{diag} (1/2,-1/2,0), \qquad  T_8=\operatorname{diag} (1,1,-2)/2\sqrt{3}, ~~\leadsto \\
Q=\operatorname{diag} (1/3+x,-2/3+x,1/3+x),
$$
where *x* is the eigenvalue of *X* given in the parenteses, for the triplets.

For the singlets, of course, omit the *su(3)* generators, as they are represented by null and the group elements by the identity, and the charge *is x*. For the antitriplets, just reverse the sign of the above generators.

If you are having trouble with confirming *all* charges' comportance with this, go back (run!) to your SM and GUT text. But there is hardly anything to be derived!

Comment: Why is the model constructed this way but not some other way? In particular, can the electric charge operator take a different form by using a different combination of $T_a$?  For example, why are $T_3$ and $T_8$ but not other $T_a$ used? Is there any logic or reason behind eq. (4) so that it must be this way but not a different way?

Comment: Oh, you are essentially asking me to demonstrate why a hit-or-miss model is unique...? I am not familiar with those, so I cannot go behind the comparative advantages of this one... This is the (poor) model they are examining, consistent with facts in the end...